# Проблемы с отображением символов в telnet

Tags: http, консоль, telnet

У меня windows 7, но в XP тоже так было:

1. Когда я захожу через cmd в telnet то когда ввожу например:

> Добро пожаловать в программу-клиент Microsoft Telnet
>   Символ переключения режима: 'CTRL+]'
>   Microsoft Telnet> open hashcode.ru 80
>   Подключение к hashcode.ru...

потом курсор встаёт на первый символ, и как бы со включённым insert начинает заменять все символы например получается:

> GET indexаловать в программу-клиент Microsoft Telnet

а остальные строки отображаются но не выделяются (я вам скопипастил содержимое моей консоли) Неужели так и должно быть? Как это исправить?

2. Если я ввожу в "Выполнить":      `telnet hashcode.ru 80` то открывается пустое окно telnet, в котором когда печатаешь символы, от них остаются лишь засечки, которые накладываются друг на друга типа такого:     _     _       _ __ и вообще не поймёшь что печатаешь! Я пробовал печатать в блокноте потом копипастить в консоль, это работает, но не то что мне нужно! Я читаю книгу про PHP, хочу понять как работает сервер но разве так поймёшь :(  Посоветуйте что делать может есть альтернатива telnet или почему так происходит, как исправить?

P.S Если допустить ошибку в "Выполнить" типа такой:    `telnet hashcod.ru 80`,то строки ошибки промелькнут вроде нормальными буквами (а не чёрточками) (правда я не успеваю как следует разглядеть ) и потом окно закрывается, почему так?

P.P.S И ещё вопрос что за     Символ переключения режима: 'CTRL+]'? Для чего он? Как его использовать?

Comment: Посмотрите GUI-клиент: http://windows.software.informer.com/download-windows-telnet-gui-client/

Answer (score 4):

putty.exe есть возможность переключать кодировки на лету